$n \times n \times n$ Rubik's cube
Is there any paper or blog which explains the maths behind $n\times n\times n$ Rubik's cube in detail along with proofs ?
I want to understand all possible configuration of $n \times n \times n$ Rubik's cube, along with proof that these are the only configurations possible. Something like the given paper which is for $3 \times 3 \times 3$ Rubik's cube.

See for example quora, or this paper.

It looks a big adventure to consider at once the $n \times n \times n$ case... Have you been working in particular on the 4 \times 4 \times 4$ case like here and also on the $2 \times 2 \times 2$ which has been considered a month or so ago on this site...

Here are a few references that I have just found on the Web:

M. E. Larsen, “Rubik’s revenge: the group theoretical solution”,
Amer. Math. Monthly, 92(1985), pp. 381–390;
M. Longridge, “God’s Algorithm Calculations for Rubik’s Cube, Rubik’s Subgroups, and Related Puzzles]1”;
Eleftherios Argyropoulos' answer on Quora provides the full formula for the number of combinations characterizing any $n \times n \times n$ Rubik's cube https://www.quora.com/How-many-combinations-on-a-Rubiks-Cube-are-possible very complete;
Michael Hutchings' recent introduction to the topic is also worth to be mentioned, and it is available here: enter link description here.
Finally, here is a paper that provides some general bounds Algorithms for Solving Rubik’s Cubes.

Lastly, I think that it would be also interesting to study the math behind the $k$-dimensional generalization of the aforementioned problem (for each integer $k \geq 2$) and Roice Nelson's article (2018) is a good starting point (see Figure 3) Abstracting the Rubik’s Cub.
